# Simple CSS Issue

Tags: css, button, width

I put a div in page, or anything in page and it automatically expand its width to the end as if I set the width 100%. Obviously I need to set a width value (like 100px) for the thing but I just want it to be as wide as the content, not a fixed one.  The longer the text is, the wider the content should be. How do I handle this? What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a width of `auto` tells block elements to expand to the entire width of the parent element.  You want either `display: table` or `display: inline-block` for it to shrink down to the width of its contents.

You can see `display: table` in action here:

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/FvGxl

Comment: Oh thank you so much. display:table; and display: inline-block both worked well. But I've got some more questions. Fist what could make this happen, why do I have to eventually set display: table? And the other thing: would there be any difference using one of the two or is there a point where they differ from each other?

Comment: Inline-block elements (think `<img />`) will appear inline with any sibbling inline elements, while table elements (think `<table/>`) will not.  Using `display: table` also generates anonymous table-row/table-cell elements, but its nothing you need to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set:

```
width: auto;
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: Sorry but this ridiculously does not work. I tried that before asking the question. It's still 100% width.